# Set custom markerId in Capacitor Google Maps Plugin

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework, mobile, capacitor

I want to use the Capacitor Plugin for Google Maps in Ionic and display custom Markers on the Map. So far so good, but i saw that you dont set an id when adding marker to the map... but when you use an MarkerClickListener you get an id Back, in what seems like in the Format 'm{index}' when you use the addMarkers(Markers[]) function.

I guess one could use that, but i rather set my own id that may come from my db, is there a way to do that? Maybe in the actual Google API and i could maybe butcher it on top of the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Cap google maps plugin from ionic, its missing A LOT of features. use the official [Angular google maps](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/main/src/google-maps) instead, here it would allow you to add an id easily and it has ALL the features google maps provide.

Comment: I will look into it, thank you. But does it support gestures n stuff? is there any disadvantage on native mobile apps towards the capacitor plugin?

Comment: what you mean by gestures n stuff? and there is not disadvantage over the native maps and the web maps. same thing but its just google has all the features while the ionic plugin is fairly new, they are missing a lot of functionality.

Comment: That api doesnt compile to use the native google maps sdk.  only capacitor one does.  which also makes using the map on mobile free :)